# How can i make border-bottom of a div tag, lunate?

Tags: css

i have a div tag like this :

```
<div id="test">
   <p>Some text here</p>
</div>
```

i want to make border-bottom of 'test' lunate! any one can help?
 it is something like this :

[image]

Comment: it would be easier to understand with some snap shot/ image/ picture than the word ***lunate***.

Comment: @KingKing i put a picture, plz help me. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/F649s/

```
#test{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border:1px solid silver;
    border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer you got from susheel is accurate, but if you want a more elliptical border, you need to set different parameters.

Set you border style to:

```
border-radius: 15em/5em;
border-top-left-radius: 0;
border-top-right-radius: 0;
```

You can play with the parameters to get a different curve or even change the `em` to `px` (but I myself thik it's better this way).